# Modify url based on a click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

I have a series of `divs` that when clicked it slides up basically a modal. The modal has a `data-attribute` that appears in the url. The issue I'm having is when I close the modal, the url still has the `data-attribute` hash, it doesn't revert back and I need it to.

This is the js:

```
$('[data-agent]').click(function() {
        var element = $(this);
        var target = element.data('agent');
        $('body').addClass('agentLoaded');
        $('[data-agent-target]').not('[data-agent-target="'+target+'"]').removeClass('active');
        $('[data-agent-target="'+target+'"]').addClass('active');
        window.location.hash = 'agent='+target;
        return false;
    });

    if(document.location.hash){
        var hash = document.location.hash.split('#')[1];
        hash = hash.replace('agent=', '');
        if(hash && $('[data-agent-target="'+hash+'"]').length) {
            $('[data-agent="'+hash+'"]').trigger('click');
        }
    }

    $('.close').click(function() {
        $('[data-agent-target]').removeClass('active');
        $('body').removeClass('agentLoaded');
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: you have to explicitely remove the part of the url in the `$('.close').click` handler.

Comment: Why not just use normal links?

Comment: Brad to give the code some more context, it's a list of Agents. When you click on one it slides up a bio and I need to create a sharable url. So everything is on one page, I am not sure how else to modify the url.

Answer (score 0):

[edit] Please see the question in the code

```
$('[data-agent]').click(function() {
    var element = $(this);
    var target = element.data('agent');
    $('body').addClass('agentLoaded');
    $('[data-agent-target]').not('[data-agent-target="'+target+'"]').removeClass('active');
    $('[data-agent-target="'+target+'"]').addClass('active');
    window.location.hash = 'agent='+target;
    return false;
});

if(document.location.hash){ /* What is this for ? */
    var hash = document.location.hash.split('#')[1];
    hash = hash.replace('agent=', '');
    if(hash && $('[data-agent-target="'+hash+'"]').length) {
        $('[data-agent="'+hash+'"]').trigger('click');
    }
}

$('.close').click(function() {
    $('[data-agent-target]').removeClass('active');
    $('body').removeClass('agentLoaded');
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Tried the changes out, but everything in the `.close` click function stopped working.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see you were triggering the click in `revert`. So i don't understand why is this `if(...)` for in your first post. So I'll edit my post and ask why is piece of code for :)

Comment: added `window.location.hash = '';` to the `.close` click event and it removed it.